# How to modify the title area for the Crisp Chat Wrapper Library

Tags: codenameone

How do i make modifications to the form that holds the Crisp Chat form. Please find attached. I cannot set the title to the form or better yet remove the title area so that the chat occupies the whole form.[image: How to modify the form containing Crisp chat]

I updated the cnlib1 with the update that you made and its working well @Shai but now am getting a runtime error with the following details.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: undefined is not an object
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:156)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1511)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:1005)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.SEBrowserComponent.executeImpl(SEBrowserComponent.java:496)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.SEBrowserComponent.access$600(SEBrowserComponent.java:67)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.SEBrowserComponent$12.run(SEBrowserComponent.java:509)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pushed an update to the library that should fix this. The update should appear in the download section within 3 hours or so. See https://github.com/codenameone/CrispCodenameOneSDK/commit/7b70120d054c080e4c21c1971e4ece4acd640873